# How to use one filter in install4j FileChooser

Tags: java, install4j, filefilter

I'm trying to find a way to start a `FileChooser` in `install4j` which filters for a special name.

I've set the option "`Use file filter`" and set a "`File filter name`" and a "`Filtered file extension`" on a `FileChooser Form Component`.

When opening the dialog during the setup I'm getting two filters:

- "All files" as default selection and
- "My Filter" as a second one.

How can I change this behaviour to use my file filter as default?

The filter itself works fine, when I change to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in install4j, which will be fixed in 5.1.7. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get an interim build which contains this fix.